# TeXworks bug - hidden parts of tex code

Tags: texworks

I use TeXworks 0.4.5 on Windows 8 and I've noticed quite an unpleasant bug. When having a rather long document (~2000 lines), some parts of the source code are not visible. Yet, they are typeset in the generated pdf.

Googling for a while took me [here](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=569) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=222). I tried everything recommended on both of these links, such as disabling babel package, turning syntax coloring off, etc. Nothing didn't help. Full document's ctrl+a -> ctrl+c -> ctrl+v didn't help either. 
When I create a copy of .tex file and open the copy, problem's gone (for that particular passage I'm looking at). However, I can not be sure about the rest of the document.

Have you ever heard of something similar?

**EDIT**: Getting line numbers on (Format -> Line numbers) seems to make invisible parts visible once again. Still, it shouldn't be necessary... (I actually find line numbers distracting, so it's not a much of solution for me.)

Comment: I had similar problem with an earlier version (0.4 or something). Very, very annoying.

Comment: Sorry Vochmelka, but this question does in my opinion not fit into this site. First: if you know it’s a bug then inform the developer(s), here you could ask for a possible workaround. Second: To your question the only answers are either “Yes, I heard from.” or “No, I did not hear yet from this issue.”

Comment: And to your avatar: I’m sure there are people, who feel offended (me not, but I consider it as bad taste). It would be wise to change to something less eccentric.

Comment: I guess you're right about informing developers. I just thought someone from TeX.SE could have experienced this issue as well  as this is the biggest (La)TeX users discussion board.___ Concerning the question: I believe it's obvious I'm looking for a solution or an answer like "that bug made me switch to another editor". Nothing against TeXworks, I still use it as I like its simple interface.___ (And as for my avatar: I'm neither fan of rudeness, nor political correctness. That's not a contradiction.)